# How does the piping of sed commands control the flow information in input and output space?

Tags: bash, sed, pipe

I'm piping several sed commands, but I don't understand how information flows.

Example:

```
command1 | command 2 | command3
```

Does piping wait until all of `command1` is completed and transferred to the output space  before then piping all of output space of command 1 to the input space of `command2`; or once a line from `command1` is transferred to the output space it then immediately piped to the input space of command 2, without waiting for the rest of the output space in `command1` to be fully filled out by the remaining lines?

I hope someone can briefly clarify this.

Comment: If you have 3 processors, all 3 commands will execute simultaneously.  cmd2 and cmd3 will (probably) immediately block on a read.  When cmd1 write some data to the pipe, cmd2 will start processing it. Those writes will probably be block buffered rather than line buffered.

Comment: stdout of cmd1 is connected to stdin of cmd2, same between cmd2 and cmd3 (all roughly at the same time). as cmd1 produces output, it is feed to cmd2 where it is processed. If cmd2 deems to emit output, then it is feed to cmd3. Can't remember exactly what happens if one of the cmds errors out, I think the whole chain is aborted. Yes, agree about buffering, can't count on line buffering, hence `cmd| tail -f` is often frustrating to people. Search here for solutions. Good luck.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, transfer from out1 to in2 MAY occur line by line, MAY occur in blocks, but there is not logic to it. I'm actually rather interested in the opposite, I want all of process 1 to finish before it transfers to input of process2.

Comment: @KamilCuk I mean when is stdout from cmd 1 is transfered to input of cmd 2?  Is it transfered on a line-per-line basis (as soon as a line is finished) , or is it transfered  ONLY WHEN comand1 has processed all the lines in it stdout1?

Comment: If you show your specific sed commands, we maybe can show you how to do it in a single pass.

Comment: @BenjaminW. tr -s [:space:] < grab.txt |
sed -r 's/\.../ /g ; s/\.«/\«./g ; s/\?«/\«?/g ; s/\!«/\«!/g' |
sed -r ':a; /((\w)+[,.]*[ ]+[,. ]*)/s/\. /\r\n /; ta' | tr '\r' '.' |
tr -s [:space:] |
sed 's/^ //' > zz.txt   Although this is the code I'm working with, although I'm more interested for my own learning and understanding.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands in a pipeline execute in parallel. They're all started at the same time and run concurrently. The right process receives the left process's output as it's generated. It doesn't have to wait until the left process finishes.

There's typically a small buffer associated with the pipe, say 4KB. Processing usually happens in 4KB chunks rather than line by line. Processes *can* flush their output more frequently if they're explicit about it or if they [disable buffering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe), but that's the default behavior.

If you don't want the programs to run in parallel then you'll want to execute them separately and store their output in temp files.

```
command1 > cmd1.out
command2 < cmd1.out > cmd2.out
command3 < cmd2.out
rm cmd1.out cmd2.out
```

Answer (score 0):

The shell starts three processes and runs them all concurrently.  Process 1 (first sed) will send output to process 2 (second sed), which will wait for input to be ready.

In principle this could be replaced by three sequential executions of sed, with temporary files storing the output of one phase for reading by the subsequent phase.

Comment: Mark, sorry I don't fully understand. Let's say I have a text file with 6000 lines that I'm cleaning up. Does process 2 until process 1 has put all of the lines (all 6000) in the output space, or does process 2 start processing immediately  (as soon as as process 1 has processed lets say line 1 but not line 2, line 1 still goes on to process 2)?